# How to add a confusion matrix to Theano examples?

Tags: theano, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I want to make use of Theano's logistic regression classifier, but I would like to make an apples-to-apples comparison with previous studies I've done to see how deep learning stacks up.  I recognize this is probably a fairly simple task if I was more proficient in Theano, but this is what I have so far.  From the tutorials on the website, I have the following code:

```
def errors(self, y):
    # check if y has same dimension of y_pred
    if y.ndim != self.y_pred.ndim:
        raise TypeError(
            'y should have the same shape as self.y_pred',
            ('y', y.type, 'y_pred', self.y_pred.type)
        )
    # check if y is of the correct datatype
    if y.dtype.startswith('int'):
        # the T.neq operator returns a vector of 0s and 1s, where 1
        # represents a mistake in prediction
        return T.mean(T.neq(self.y_pred, y))
```

I'm pretty sure this is where I need to add the functionality, but I'm not certain how to go about it.  What I need is either access to y_pred and y for each and every run (to update my confusion matrix in python) or to have the C++ code handle the confusion matrix and return it at some point along the way.  I don't think I can do the former, and I'm unsure how to do the latter.  I've done some messing around with an update function along the lines of:

```
def confuMat(self, y):
    x=T.vector('x')
    classes = T.scalar('n_classes')
    onehot = T.eq(x.dimshuffle(0,'x'),T.arange(classes).dimshuffle('x',0))
    oneHot = theano.function([x,classes],onehot)
    yMat = T.matrix('y')
    yPredMat = T.matrix('y_pred')
    confMat = T.dot(yMat.T,yPredMat)
    confusionMatrix = theano.function(inputs=[yMat,yPredMat],outputs=confMat)

    def confusion_matrix(x,y,n_class):
        return confusionMatrix(oneHot(x,n_class),oneHot(y,n_class))

    t = np.asarray(confusion_matrix(y,self.y_pred,self.n_out))
    print (t)
```

But I'm not completely clear on how to get this to interface with the function in question and give me a numpy array I can work with.
I'm quite new to Theano, so hopefully this is an easy fix for one of you.  I'd like to use this classifer as my output layer in a number of configurations, so I could use the confusion matrix with other architectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a brute force sort of a way. You need an output for a prediction first. Create a function for it.

```
 prediction = theano.function(
        inputs = [index],
        outputs = MLPlayers.predicts,
        givens={
                x: test_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]})
```

In your test loop, gather the predictions...

```
labels = labels + test_set_y.eval().tolist() 
for mini_batch in xrange(n_test_batches):
    wrong = wrong + int(test_model(mini_batch))   
    predictions = predictions + prediction(mini_batch).tolist()
```

Now create confusion matrix this way:

```
    correct = 0
    confusion = numpy.zeros((outs,outs), dtype = int)
    for index in xrange(len(predictions)):
        if labels[index] is predictions[index]:
            correct = correct + 1
        confusion[int(predictions[index]),int(labels[index])] = confusion[int(predictions[index]),int(labels[index])] + 1
```

You can find this kind of an implementation [in this repository](http://ragavvenkatesan.github.io/Convolutional-Neural-Networks/).